# How to Debug postgres connection issues on google cloud compute VM

Tags: postgresql, google-compute-engine

When trying to connect to postgres using psql thus: `sql -d DATABASE_NAME -U postgres -h PUBLIC_VM_IP`

I get the following error: `psql: error: could not connect to server: Operation timed out`

My configuration is

1. Google cloudcompute vm instance e2-micro (2 vCPUs, 1 GB memory).
2. The container image is set to `gcr.io/google/postgresql12:latest`
3. I have two env vars set up in the VM via the console: a) `POSTGRES_DB=MY_DATABASE_NAME` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD=MY_PASSWORD`
4. I have network tags set to `allow_postgres`.
5. I have a firewall rule named `allow_posgres` with the following properties:

- logs: Off
- Network: default
- Priority: 1000
- Direction: Ingress
- Action on match: Allow
- Targets: Target tag allow-postgres
- Source filters: IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 and my computer's IP
- Protocols and ports: tcp:5432
- Enforcement: Enabled
- Insights: None

If I ssh into the instance and do `docker ps` I see: `gcr.io/stackdriver-agents/stackdriver-logging-agent:1.8.4` as the only listed running container, which doesn't seem right. I should see the postgres container running too right?

If so, how do I change my configuration in the console to ensure that container is running and how can I further debug the connection issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried running the image you specified I was always getting en error (seen after I logged in to this VM):

```
  #########################[ Error ]#########################
  #  The startup agent encountered errors. Your container   #
  #  was not started. To inspect the agent's logs use       #
  #  'sudo journalctl -u konlet-startup' command.           #
  ###########################################################
```

The logs displayed by `journalctl` also gave no indication what's wrong.

So - I went to marketplace and looked for [postgresql 12](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/google/postgresql12). After I clicked the `Show Pull Command` button I got a link to this image: `marketplace.gcr.io/google/postgresql12:latest`.

I created a new VM (default settings) and used above image url to deploy a container. I assigned a proper network tag to allow connections on 5432 port and clicked `create` button and created a firewall rule just as you described in your question.

After I logged in to a new VM I ran `docker ps` and seen that the container is running:

```
wb@pg1 ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS     NAMES
37b651f9c383   marketplace.gcr.io/google/postgresql12:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   28 seconds ago   Up 19 seconds             klt-pg1-maok
```

After that I tried connecting from the outside:

```
wb@cloudshell:~$ psql -h xx.xxx.xxx.xxx -U postgres
psql (13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1), server 12.6 (Debian 12.6-1.pgdg90+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

I was able to list all databases:

```
postgres=# \l
                                 List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)
```

As you can see I got in with no issues so you may try doing the same. As you can see I didn't configure any variables nor database password since it was for testing purposes.

Use the link I found in the Marketplace and it should work.

Additionally

Comment: This is right. I guess the image I was using was bad. Thanks!!!